# Why isn't the mutationObserver working?

Tags: javascript

From my understanding mutationObserver is used similarly to how eventListeners are. I'm trying to use it in place of an event listener, so I can have a div react to changes. My problem is nothing is being printed to the console when I type something in the div. Something should be printed to the console, but it's not and I'm not sure why. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    <div contenteditable="true" class="input"></div>
    <div class="display"></div>


        let input= document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0];
        let displat= document.getElementsByClassName("dispaly")[0];

        let config={attributes:true, childlist:true, characterData:true};

        let observer= new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
            console.log(mutation.type);
             });
          }); 
    observer.observe(input,config);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote "childlist", it must be "childList", with the L in caps.